# clear sorting button of ngtable is calling form submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-submit

i am using ng-table inside a form.

```
    <form role="form" name="frmCommand"  class="formValidCommand" novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="frmCommand.$valid && vm.saveCommandChanges()">
```

i have a clear sorting button on the table.

```
                <button ng-click="storeCommandsTableParams.sorting({})" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Clear sorting</button>
```

clicking this button is calling vm.saveCommandChanges() instead of clearing the sort.

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default [type attribute value for `button` tag is `submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), so when you click on it it will trigger its parent form's submit event which is captured by `ng-submit` directive. So try change it to `button` type so that submit event does not happen.

ie.

```
<button 
   type="button"
   ng-click="storeCommandsTableParams.sorting({})" 
   class="btn btn-default pull-right">Clear sorting</button>
```